# Javascript extend Array so it duplicates and reverses

Tags: javascript

If I have an array like `[1,2,3,4]`, and I want to duplicate and reverse it, how do I get it to return `[1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1]`?

```
Array.prototype.duplicateAndReverse = function() {
  const initial = this;
  const reversed = initial.reverse();
  return initial.concat(reversed);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?  It returns [4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1]

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):  "The reverse() method reverses an array **in place**. The first array element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the first."  Your call to reverse modifies `initial`.

Comment: Unlike something like `.replace()` where the original item remains the same, `.reverse()` will actually modify whichever object you use it on. So `const reversed = initial.reverse()` is actually modifying `initial` AND setting `reversed`, thus both of your arrays are now reversed.

Comment: thanks @Amy.  Now i undertand my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
Array.prototype.duplicateAndReverse = function() {
    const initial = this;
    const reversed = initial.slice().reverse();
    return initial.concat(reversed);
}

var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
alert(myArray.duplicateAndReverse());
```

Your code is reversing `initial` as well as setting `reversed` to the result, so you have two identical (reversed) arrays. Instead, use `.slice()` to duplicate the initial array, and reverse that instead.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

for(var len = arr.length; len; len--)
  arr.push(arr[len - 1]);
  
console.log(arr);
```

I don't recommend you mess with `Array.prototype` but here is what you want:

```js
Array.prototype.duplicateAndReverse = function() {
  let res = this.slice(); // create another copy so the original array will stay intact
  for(var len = res.length; len; len--)
    res.push(res[len - 1]);
  return res;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(arr.duplicateAndReverse());
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that you tried to reverse the initial array in place.
Use the following optimized solution:

```js
Array.prototype.duplicateAndReverse = function() {
    return this.concat(this.slice().reverse());
} 

console.log([1,2,3,4].duplicateAndReverse());
```

To retain the original array and create its reversed copy use [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function combined with [Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) function

Answer (score 2):

This is  your problem because `reverse()` also reverse the original array
arr

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
var dup = arr.reverse()
console.log(arr) // => [4, 3, 2, 1]
console.log(dup) // => [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You need to clone the original array first

```
var dup = arr.slice().reverse()
```

And then you can concat the 2 arrays to get the result. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Oriental solution, hihi.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var newArr = [];

arr.forEach((_,i) => newArr.unshift(arr[arr.length-i-1]) && newArr.push(arr[arr.length-i-1]))

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: I've used `_` to tell everyone who look at my code, that I haven't used the first argument of the `forEach()` function, which is `element`. The second argument is index - `i` of that `element`. That `i` is all I need here :)

Comment: O ok.  So if You don't use that _ what will happen?

Comment: Nothing :D You will just mislead others, because they will look for this argument in your code. But if you replace it with `_` they will know that you haven't used it **anywhere** in your code :)

Comment: oh ok.  Thanks.  I have never seen that before.

Comment: It may be useful for you in the future. Remember it :P